# Error in opening a CSV file with specifying row.name using R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, error-handling

I have a big df (CSV format) that looks like:

```
miRNAs <- c('mmu_mir-1-3p','mmu_mir-1-5p','mmu-mir-6-5p','mmu-mir-6-3p')
cca <- c('12854','5489','54485','2563')
ccb <- c('124','589','5465','25893')
taa <- c('12854','589','5645','763')
df <- data.frame(miRNAs,cca,ccb,taa)
```

and I want to use this df in DESeq2 analyses. I made this df unique by using `unique(df)` and tried to open using `countData <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="df.csv", row.name="miRNAs", sep = ","))` but it gives this error

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Since I made the df `unique` I don't know why this error keeps popping up. Basically why I want to read my df in that way is that I want to get the list of my column headers `(except the first column)` when I type `colnames(df)`. Because I need to do FALSE TRUE test to see if match these are matching with row names of another file called phenotype.csv `all(rownames(phenotype) == colnames(countData))`

Comment: if you have to have duplicated entries in the first column of df, it will give you this kind of error. Can you check table(duplicated(df$miRNAs))

Comment: I have 1978 FALSE and 44 TRUE

Comment: Yeah, so in your df, there are actually duplicated miRNAs (based on column miRNA) and they have different counts, which makes them non-duplicated.

Comment: I used this to remove the first column duplicates `new_df <- df[!duplicated(df$miRNAs),,drop=FALSE]` is this correct?

Comment: yes, this is ok, then write.csv(new_df,"new_df.csv",row.names=FALSE)

Comment: Cool :) So the error comes with the unique or write.csv?

Comment: it was basically becasue of the duplicated gene names in the first column :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `row.name="miRNAs"` argument you are not accessing the respective column, but are using a length one character vector. That then gets recycled and that's why you get the error. Import without the `row.names` argument and if you really want that variable as row names instead of a column, then do that after the import:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  miRNAs = c('mmu_mir-1-3p','mmu_mir-1-5p','mmu-mir-6-5p','mmu-mir-6-3p'),
  cca = c('12854','5489','54485','2563'),
  ccb = c('124','589','5465','25893'),
  taa = c('12854','589','5645','763')
  )

rownames(df) <- df$miRNAs
df$miRNAs <- NULL
df
#>                cca   ccb   taa
#> mmu_mir-1-3p 12854   124 12854
#> mmu_mir-1-5p  5489   589   589
#> mmu-mir-6-5p 54485  5465  5645
#> mmu-mir-6-3p  2563 25893   763
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't want `miRNAs` to be in my list when I type `colnames(countData)` I need to have just `cca` `ccb` and `taa`

Comment: I get  error again it seems that this is not compatible with my original csv file. Lets say in this way that, I want to have the `csv` file opened in a way that when I type `colnames(countData)` I don't want to get the header of the first column which is `miRNAs` in the list.

Comment: I tried to used this code `names(countData)[1] <- ""` but when I type colnames(countData), `""` appears in the list as of the header for the first column

Comment: there is no error message, just `""` comes in my list when I type `colnames(countData)`

Comment: I get that's happening when you just use an empty sting. But in the comment before, you were saying that you got an error message when you tried to use the solution I proposed

Comment: I mean the same error that I mentioned in this question. And the error was because of the duplications in names in the first column `(miRNAs)` in the original file

Comment: Row names must be unique because they are used to query rows. Similarly, the column names of a data frame are required to be able to access the variables. Your problem seems to be about the aesthetics of the print out. I don't think that there is a built-in function for what you are trying to do, as this is R and not Excel and the console is not really about aesthetics.